# Rails: Is it improper to freak out during validation (with exceptions)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, controller

You have a `Lung` model. In it, you put:

`validates_presence_of :human_id`

Users of your app have *no* control over whether or not `human_id` is set; the application should be doing it automatically.

If `:human_id` were ever *not* present, it doesn't help your users to tell them "this lung isn't attached to a human", because your users won't be able to do anything about it. Is it time for your model to freak out and throw an exception?

Should your models ever care about the severity of a given validation error? Is that part of business logic? Should models ever throw exceptions during validation, or should the controllers be responsible to interpreting the "dumb" validation from the model and generating useful data for the view?

Edit: If this is an acceptable thing to do, are there any conventions regarding *how* to throw exceptions during a model's validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up my ActiveRecord migration so that the `human_id` column cannot be `null`. That way you'd get an exception anyway if it's not set.

```
create_table :lungs do |t|
  t.integer :human_id, :null => false
  ...
end
```

Comment: Does this mean I wouldn't validate against it in my model?

Comment: If it's not something that the users can do anything about, then no.

Comment: I like this way of thinking about it!

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be raised as a exception. The Application would be putting the human_id in most of the cases and only in exceptional cases the human_id might not be present, like say an crafted request or timed logout in the backend. Since these are exceptional cases it's worthwhile to throw exceptions instead of letting the controller handle it.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding validations are not the right place to check this kind of model consistency. Validations are only for user generated input.

The question is: how would it be possible that a Lung is created without a human id? If the answer is only through a programming order, you should propably fix that bug and create some test cases for it. Or if you really want to check it every time, you could check it inside a before_save callback.